# Why LeftBarButtonItem doesn't appear in the navigationbar in swift

Tags: swift, swift2, navigationbar

I have two view A and view B.

From view A to view B, I do not use navigation controller, I used `performSegueWithIdentifier()` and I don't want to use navigation controller to pass view A to view B.

But in the view B, I want to add a leftBarButtonItem in the navigation bar(I have embed a navigation controller for view B) like a back button with a arrow.

In order to achieve 100% same with the system backbitten with arrow. I use `NSMutableAttributedString` and `UIButton`. code is below:

```
let string = "< Retour" as NSString
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string as String)

let ArrowAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)]
let TextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)]

attributedString.addAttributes(ArrowAttributes, range: string.rangeOfString("<"))
attributedString.addAttributes(ArrowAttributes, range: string.rangeOfString(" Retour"))

let backbutton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
backbutton.addTarget(self, action: "back:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
backbutton.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(customView: backbutton), animated: true)
        rightBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Ok", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "save:")
```

But I can not see left button in the navigation bar in view B…why I can not see it in the navigation bar? Why the left button disappear?

Thank you very much.

I have tried the new code for a label, but it doesn't work yet...

```
let barButtonBackStr = "< Back"
let attributedBarButtonBackStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: barButtonBackStr as String)
attributedBarButtonBackStr.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,
                                                value: UIFont(
                                                    name: "AmericanTypewriter-Bold",
                                                    size: 18.0)!,
                                                range: NSRange(
                                                    location:0,
                                                    length:1))
let label = UILabel()
label.attributedText = attributedBarButtonBackStr
label.sizeToFit()
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
        self.navigationController!.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(newBackButton, animated: true)
```

Thank you

Comment: Try to use the debug hierarchy tool in Debug > View Debugging > Capture view hierarchy to see what is happening (check if a view is hidding your button, check if you need to bring your button to front etc.)

Comment: I am sorry I made a mistake and I have update it

Comment: Also you didn't set any frame to your UIButton before set it to your navigationItem

Answer (score 1):

Try a `backbutton.sizeToFit()` you'll see your button

You create a button but you never set the frame

You can also set the frame directly instead of `sizeToFit()` method like `backbutton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)`

PS: `TextAttributes` wasn't used

Comment: Please check update, I used `sizeToFit()` to label, but it doesn't work, why ?Thank you

Comment: You need change this `self.navigationController!.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(newBackButton, animated: true)`  to this  `self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(newBackButton, animated: false)`

Answer (score 0):

You must write it to :

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     ...
}
```

Try to set a breakpoint after your UI design and try to launch the Debug View Hierarchy to see if your button exist or is hidden by another object

[image]

Next, after you have set your button try to make:

```
self.navigationController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.customView.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, code is in `viewDidLoad()`, I tried your solution to add code in `viewDidAppear ` , but it doesn't works yet..

Comment: I check it, there is not a button or label, I think I didn't really add it to the navigation bar, why ? Thank you